# Run cURL from CLI with return transfer

Tags: php, laravel, curl, command-line-interface

Is there a way to set curl to something like `curl --url localhost/mysite/file.php --returntransfer 1`? I have a script that I'd rather execute from CLI due the many things is handles and I'd like to see the output while it's processing. (By the way; I'm accessing a Laravel route as --url parameter, but I don't think that matters)

Comment: Could you show sample script and show result you get and expected result?

Comment: Right now I'm doing from my Terminal `curl --url localhost/myfile.php`. I've been reading about the `-K` option and I'm now providing a config file with only content `RETURNTRANSFER=TRUE` but it's giving me a `.. had unsupported trailing` message. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. And I expect to see every 500th iteration a simple output message telling `I'm at index $i` so I know the script is still running. The total runtime will be several hours to process all the data.